# Asp.Net IdentityUser add custom List Property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am fairly new to coding with asp.net so there might be an obvious answere to my question but I haven't found one yet.

So currently I am developing a site for project management and I want the users to get notified when an event happens, eg. they were added to a new project, a project has been updated etc.

For that I have expanded the IdentityUser Model with a new property List

```
    public class CojectUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public List<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    }

    public class Notification
    {
        public int NotificationID { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool Seen { get; set; }
    }
```

When an event happens I add them to the user's notification list and update the user via the userManager.

```
public class EventBroker<T> : IEventBroker<T>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<CojectUser> userManager;

        public EventBroker(UserManager<CojectUser> userMgr, IUserValidator<CojectUser> userValid)
        {
            userManager = userMgr;
        }

        public async Task NotifyAsync(Message<T> message, List<UserRole> recipients)
        {
            foreach (var user in recipients)
            {
                var cojectUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.Name);
                if (cojectUser != null)
                {
                    if (cojectUser.Notifications == null)
                    {
                        cojectUser.Notifications = new List<Notification>();
                    }
                    cojectUser.Notifications.Add(new Notification
                    {
                        Message = message.Information,
                        Seen = false
                    });
                    IdentityResult result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(cojectUser);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        throw new UserUpdateFailException();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to save the custom data to the database, but I am unable to load it again from database.
When I want to display the user's notifications userManager retrieves an user object with null as notification list. Even though the data is stored in database.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            CojectUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if(user.Notifications == null)
            {
                user.Notifications = new List<Notification>();
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

Data in database:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserManager don't eager load properties by default.

You should use DatabaseContext directly.

```
var user = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Notifications).Where(u => u.Id == user.Id).ToList();
```